# SetSocketOption not working for SocketOptionName.ChecksumCoverage C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sockets, server, network-programming

I am trying to set an option for my UDP socket in C# .Net. I am pretty sure I am doing everything as the Microsoft documents stated; however it is throwing an An 'invalid argument was supplied' exception.

```
    Socket socket;
    socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));

    // MUST BE BIND FIRST BEFORE SETTING OPTIONS!
    // To find out what option can be used with what:
    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1011kecd(v=vs.110).aspx
    socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Udp, SocketOptionName.NoChecksum, 0);
    socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Udp, SocketOptionName.ChecksumCoverage, 1);
```

The exception is thrown right when setting the SocketOptionName.ChecksumCoverage option to 1 or true. I looked through the documents, it should be valid arguments. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you have "no checksum" and then have ChecksumCoverage?

Comment: Even when commenting out the 'no checksum', it still throws the exception

Comment: SetSocketOption the third parameter is optional.  So I would omit.  Both NoCheckSum and ChecksumCoverage have no value so you do not need the third parameter.  I would omit the NoCheckSum  from your code.

Comment: There is actually no overloaded method for SetSocketOption that does not take a thrid value. They do have values. You can get the values like this:
   int NoChecksum = (int)socket.GetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Udp, SocketOptionName.NoChecksum);
        Console.WriteLine("NoChecksum value: " + NoChecksum);

Comment: Try for 3rd parameter null.